# Is it possible to protect the 'this' reference binding a function within an object?

Tags: javascript

Given the following JavaScript (the relevant HTML will be posted at the bottom of the question):

```
var app = {
    // other objects from 'messages' array removed for brevity
    'messages': [{
        'author': 'Maya Angelou',
        'quote': "If you don't like something, change it. If you can't change it, change your attitude."
    }],
    'textProp': 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
    'outputTo': document.querySelector('#output'),
    'trigger': document.querySelector('#load'),
    'quote': function () {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.messages.length),
            f = document.createElement('figure'),
            c = document.createElement('figcaption'),
            frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        f[this.textProp] = this.messages[n].quote;
        c[this.textProp] = this.messages[n].author;
        frag.appendChild(f);
        frag.appendChild(c);
        this.outputTo.innerHTML = '';
        this.outputTo.appendChild(frag);
    }
};
```

We can call the `quote()` function from outside of the object using the following:

```
document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', app.quote.bind(app));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yj7v/1/).

Or by simply calling the function directly (not bound as a callback to an event-handler):

```
app.quote();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yj7v/2/).

However, I *tried* to create an event-handler within the object itself, using:

```
'clickhandler': function(){
    this.trigger.addEventListener('click', this.quote);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yj7v/3/).

This, of course, failed (as expected, since `this` here is (using an IIFE) [this `Window` object](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yj7v/4/)).

I realise that `this` will, while the object is being created/prior to its initialisation, refer to the `Window` object, but is there a way I'm not seeing to create, and trigger, the event-handling within the object itself?

I realise that a large portion of my imaginary internet points comes specifically from JavaScript, but learning it accidentally leads to moments of utter confusion and inadequacy; this is not to excuse my ignorance but to explain it.

Finally, the HTML (such as it is):

```
<button id="load">Switch message</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Incidentally, I've looked at the following linked/suggested questions:

For clarity, I'm trying to create the object itself and have the event-handling created and assigned entirely within/'by' the object, without having to call its methods afterwards. That's the part where I'm stuck (and which I suspect may be impossible).

- [Is it possible to reference object within the same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829021/is-it-possible-to-reference-object-within-the-same-object) - and I'm not seeing the relevance (though perhaps I'm simply tired at this point).
- [Is it possible to implicitly reference a member of the parent object from within a function of a child object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114756/is-it-possible-to-implicitly-reference-a-member-of-the-parent-object-from-within) - this suggests that the only possible way would be to extend the `app` object following its initialisation by adding a new method, which is do-able, but does rather go against what I *want* to do (and I realise that life is not fair, but even so...).
- [Javascript using bind within an object, how can I access object this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309184/javascript-using-bind-within-an-object-how-can-i-access-object-this) - deals with an event-handler, but doesn't seem directly applicable. I may be misunderstanding though.

Comment: `this.trigger.addEventListener('click', this.quote.bind(this));`

Comment: What `this` refers to depends on how you call `clickhandler`. If you call it "normally", like `app.clickhandler()`, `this` refers to `app` and you should just use `.bind` as suggested by  epascarello . See [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196). Your problem has nothing to do with using object literals.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3yj7v/5/

Comment: @epascarello: what I was trying to do (my question may not have been sufficiently clear, for which I apologise) is to bind the event-handler within the object itself, in order to *not* have to call the function. Essentially to create *just* the object and have the handling assigned without making any calls to the object or its methods.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. An object literal consists only of `key: value` pairs, where `value` can be any expression. But those expressions don't have access to the object itself since it does not exist yet. So in short: You can't reference the object itself during initialization.

Answer (score 1):

As you specified if you just want to create a new object you probably need to go this way. I think what ever you do you still need to execute something - be it instantiate an object or run a specific init function that binds the click.

```
 var App = function App(){
    this.clickhandler()
    }

    App.prototype =
    {
        'messages': [{
            'author': 'Maya Angelou',
                'quote': "If you don't like something, change it. If you can't change it, change your attitude."
        }, {
            'author': 'Richard Feynman',
                'quote': "Hell, if I could explain it to the average person, it wouldn't have been worth the Nobel prize."
        }, {
            'author': 'Eddie Izzard',
                'quote': "Cats have a scam going – you buy the food, they eat the food, they fuck off; that's the deal."
        }, {
            'author': 'George Carlin',
                'quote': "I would never want to be a member of a group whose symbol was a man nailed to two pieces of wood. Especially if it's me!"
        }],
            'textProp': 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
            'outputTo': document.querySelector('#output'),
            'trigger': document.querySelector('#load'),
            'quote': function () {
                console.log('hey')
            var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.messages.length),
                f = document.createElement('figure'),
                c = document.createElement('figcaption'),
                frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            f[this.textProp] = this.messages[n].quote;
            c[this.textProp] = this.messages[n].author;
            frag.appendChild(f);
            frag.appendChild(c);
            this.outputTo.innerHTML = '';
            this.outputTo.appendChild(frag);
        },
        'clickhandler' : function(){
            this.trigger.addEventListener('click', this.quote.bind(this));
        }
    };
    //just create an object
    app = new App();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LwrvT/

Answer (score 1):

At some point, you will need to `.bind()` the method to your `app` (unless you [avoid the use of `this` and replace it with `app`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572) everywhere). This is however not necessarily in the place where you *pass* the `app.quote` method (e.g. bind as the event listener), but might be directly after the declaration of the `app` object:

```
var app = {
    …,
    quote: function() {
        … this …
    }
};
app.quote = app.quote.bind(app);
```

If you have Underscore around, you might use the [`bindAll` helper function](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) for this:

```
var app = _.bindAll({
    …,
    quote: function() {
        … this …
    }
}, "quote");
```

---

If you are [not in an object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572) - it could be a constructor, IEFE, whatever - you can `.bind()` the function directly at the place of its declaration:

```
function App() {
    …
    this.quote = function() {
         … this …
    }.bind(this);
}
```

With coffeescript or ES6, you can also use the fat-arrow function syntax as a sugar for this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of object literal, you could do the below:

```
var app = new function () {
    this.messages = [{
        'author': 'Maya Angelou',
            'quote': "If you don't like something, change it. If you can't change it, change your attitude."
    }, {
        'author': 'Richard Feynman',
            'quote': "Hell, if I could explain it to the average person, it wouldn't have been worth the Nobel prize."
    }, {
        'author': 'Eddie Izzard',
            'quote': "Cats have a scam going – you buy the food, they eat the food, they fuck off; that's the deal."
    }, {
        'author': 'George Carlin',
            'quote': "I would never want to be a member of a group whose symbol was a man nailed to two pieces of wood. Especially if it's me!"
    }];
    this.textProp = 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
    this.outputTo =  document.querySelector('#output');
    this.trigger = document.querySelector('#load');
    this.quote = function () {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.messages.length),
            f = document.createElement('figure'),
            c = document.createElement('figcaption'),
            frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        f[this.textProp] = this.messages[n].quote;
        c[this.textProp] = this.messages[n].author;
        frag.appendChild(f);
        frag.appendChild(c);
        this.outputTo.innerHTML = '';
        this.outputTo.appendChild(frag);
    };
    this.trigger.addEventListener('click', this.quote.bind(this));
};
```

**[SEE THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/jGh33/1/)**

Comment: Is there a reason why you have one long expression using the comma operator, instead of using multiple expression statements?

Comment: @FelixKling No, it should be `;`, I just copied the code from the op's fiddle and forgot to change it :)

Comment: @Bergi Although the constructor could be leaked this way, but this is under your control, right? Unless you use `app.constructor`, there should be no problems.

Comment: I'm not so much concerned with "loosing control", but more with memory consumption. There exist two completely superflouos objects which could so easily be avoided. E.g, omit the `new` and let the function end in `return this;}.call({})`.

Answer (score 0):

The this variable is just referencing app. So just use app.

```
var app = {
    someVar: 'thing',
    someMethod: function(){
        alert(app.someVar);
    }
};
```

or you can do

```
function createApp(){
    var app = {};

    app.someVar = 'thing';
    app.someMethod = function(){
        alert(app.someVar);
    };
    return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small change. Declaring the Object before initializing its properties might help your usecase.

```
var app = {};

app["messages"] = "test message";
app["textProp'] = 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

app['quote']= function () {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.messages.length),
            f = document.createElement('figure'),
            c = document.createElement('figcaption'),
            frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        f[app.textProp] = app.messages[n].quote;
}
```